# everything() within select() in r is throwing error?

Tags: r, select

I don't know why suddenly I have started **getting error** in using `everything()` while reordering the columns in `select()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(hp, everything())
```

Error in select(., hp, everything()) :
unused arguments (hp, everything())

```
iris %>% 
  select(Petal.Width, everything())
```

Error in select(., Petal.Width, everything()) :
unused arguments (Petal.Width, everything())

Is there some change in `everything()` or `select()` or am I doing some very stupid mistake ?

Comment: Check `conflicts()` to make sure you are using `dplyr::select` and not a different `select` function from some other package. If you loaded another package after `dplyr` that has a function named `select`, it might be masking `dplyr::select.

Comment: You could also verify - does it work without the `everything()`? And does `mtcars %>% dplyr::select(hp, everything())` work?

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas you are right, I didn't think of checking conflicts on `select()` rather i was thinking the same for `everything()`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.  I think @GregorThomas was correct when he suggested a conflict.

Comment: @Limey, yes it was a conflict from `MASS` package.